# C#-Selenium: Open an EXE file using WinWindow property in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

We launch URIs using WebDrivers, just like that can we open or launch an exe/Windows application using WinWindows or anyother selenium properties?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium launches browser sessions for you, it doesn't and nor it should launch exe/applications.

If you need to do so, it is suggested to launch it from the application code you are using selenium driver in (probably Java or C#).